# Events not working on SVG made with Snap.svg

Tags: javascript, css, events, snap.svg

Hello my fellow developers of code.

I'm trying to implement a floating menu icon using Snap.svg. I'm having this issue where I can draw the icon, but am unable to capture any events on the icon. I find if I don't overlay all my svg then I can click it, but I don't want this to be the case in the layout.

Below is my code and a JS fiddle where I'm testing to see if I can just change the colour of the graphic to black after clicking it.

```js
/* HTML containers */
const menuDIV = document.getElementById("MENU");
menuDIV.style.opacity = 1.0;
menuDIV.hidden = false;

const UIDIV = document.getElementById("UI");
UIDIV.hidden = false;

const roomWidth = $(window).width();
const roomHeight = $(window).height();
const origin = {
    x : roomWidth/2,
    y: roomHeight/2
};

/* SVG Stuff */
const menuPaper = Snap(roomWidth,roomHeight);
const UIPaper = Snap(roomWidth,roomHeight);
const smallMenuButtonPaper = Snap(100,100);

$(menuPaper.node).appendTo('#MENU');
$(UIPaper.node).appendTo('#UI');
$(smallMenuButtonPaper.node).appendTo('#UI');

smallMenuButtonPaper.attr({
    id : "small-menu-button",
    class : "overlay"
})

function menuButton(shape){
    this.icon = shape;
    let _this = this;

    /**************************** This is not working */
    function changeColour(){
        _this.icon.attr({
         fill : "black"
        })
    }
    this.icon.click(changeColour);
};

function drawMenuButton(){
    let rect = smallMenuButtonPaper.rect(10,10,50,50).attr({
     fill:"red"
    });

    return new menuButton(rect);
}

function hexaFace(face,id,heading,translate){
    this.face = face;
    this.text = heading;
    this.translateDirection = translate;
    this.buttonID = id;
    let _this = this;
    let old_colour = this.face.node.attributes.fill.value;

    function mouseOver(){
        _this.face.animate({
            transform: 't'+ _this.translateDirection[0]+','+_this.translateDirection[1]
          }, 200, mina.linear)
        _this.face.attr({fill:"black"});  
    }

    function mouseOut(){
        _this.face.animate({
            transform: 's1'
          }, 200, mina.linear)
        _this.face.attr({fill:old_colour});
    }
    this.face.hover(mouseOver,mouseOut);
}



function drawHexagonMenu(){
// Draw Hexagonal Menu
    // Draw Hexagon faces from origin
    let vertices = 6; 
    let angleInc = (360/vertices);

    let dist = roomHeight/3;

    let hexagonMenu = new Array(vertices).fill(0).map((_,i)=>{
        let x1 = origin.x + dist*Snap.cos((angleInc/2)*9+angleInc*i);
        let y1 = origin.y + dist*Snap.sin((angleInc/2)*9+angleInc*i);
        let x2 = origin.x + dist*Snap.cos((angleInc/2)*9+angleInc*(i+1));
        let y2 = origin.y + dist*Snap.sin((angleInc/2)*9+angleInc*(i+1));
        let face = menuPaper.polyline(origin.x,origin.y,x1,y1,x1,y1,x2,y2).attr({
            fill : "purple",
            stroke : "white",
            class : "menu-slice"
        });
        
        return new hexaFace(face,i,_,[((x1+x2)/2-origin.x)/5,((y1+y2)/2-origin.y)/5]);
    })

    return hexagonMenu;
}

function drawGrid(){
    let divisor = 10;
    let grid; 
    let noVertLines;
    let noHorizontalLines;
    let strokeWeight;
    // Determine amount of vertical lines 
    let vertLinesIncrement = roomWidth/(roomSize[0]*10);
    let horizontalLinesIncrement = roomHeight/(roomSize[1]*10);
    // Draw lines
    let verticalLines = new Array(roomSize[0]*10).fill(0);
    let horizontalLines = new Array(roomSize[0]*10).fill(0);
    verticalLines = verticalLines.map((x,i)=>{
        if (i%divisor == 0) {
            strokeWidth = "2px"; 
        }
        else {
            strokeWidth = "1px";
        }
        return UIPaper.line(vertLinesIncrement*i,0,vertLinesIncrement*i,roomHeight).attr(
            {stroke : "grey",
            strokeWidth : strokeWidth,
            opacity : 0.75}
        );
    })
    horizontalLines = horizontalLines.map((x,i)=>{
        if (i%divisor == 0) {
            strokeWidth = "2px"; 
        }
        else {
            strokeWidth = "1px";
        }
        return UIPaper.line(0,horizontalLinesIncrement*i,roomWidth,horizontalLinesIncrement*i).attr(
            {stroke : "grey",
             strokeWidth : strokeWidth, 
            opacity : 0.75}
        );
    })
}

function createPrototype(){
    drawGrid();
    let hexagonMenu = drawHexagonMenu();
    drawMenuButton();
}
let roomSize = [10,10,4];   
createPrototype();
```

```css
.overlay{
    position : absolute;
    /* position : fixed; */
}

#small-menu-button {
    
    top:5px;
    right : 25px;
    position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div id="UI" class="overlay"> </div>

</div>

<div id="MENU" class="overlay"> </div>

</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tonetechnician/03rxent6/63/)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. It feels like it shouldn't be too hard a problem... Just something overlapping or something, but my knowledge of CSS and web layout isn't deep enough to know exactly where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I've answered my own question with the help my younger brother! :D

I was giving my menu button two different positions in the CSS which was obviously confusing the event handler.